# How to structure spatio-temporal data for LSTM model input

Tags: lstm, machine-learning-model, feature-construction

I have a dataset representing species distribution (binary presence/absence) and I would like to use a LSTM to predict future species distribution. I am having trouble working out how I should shape my data for the model's input.

Here's an example of my data structure (`df.shape = (459481, 16)`):
[image]

The 'Sensor' column represents different sensors, the 'Species' column represents distinct species and the 'Day' column represents each time step. The target is the binary "isPresent" column.

For each species, the same sensors are recording for the same timesteps (in principle, although there is some missing data for some timesteps and some sensors).

All other features are environmental features related to the sensors, they do not change over time.

I know that LSTM models expect an input shape of Samples, Timesteps, Features.
I would like some advice on how to structure my data, in particular, should the Sample dimension be the Sensors or the Species?

I have tried running the LSTM with the data formatted as it is, but it doesn't converge. This is my current code for running the model:

```
n_steps = 7  # Number of timesteps
n_features = len(feature_cols)  # Number of input features

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_generator, epochs=10, validation_data=val_generator, verbose=0, callbacks=[checkpoint, csv_logger])
```

Comment: How many sensors do you have? Have you tried a more complex architecture?